# DateTimeFormatter with nested optionals

Tags: java

I've got three types of ISO dates: `yyyy`, `yyyy-MM`, `yyyy-MM-dd`. In other words, increasingly getting more precise from year to month to day. Should a field be absent, it should be mapped to the lowest possible value (missing day -> first day of the month // missing month -> first month of the year).

A day cannot ever be there without a month, so I thought it would work fine using nested brackets:

```
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy[-MM[-dd]]");
        LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse("2019-08-10", dtf); // ok
        ld = LocalDate.parse("2019-08", dtf); // error
        ld = LocalDate.parse("2019", dtf); // error
```

But alas, the two bottom ones spit out a DateTimeParseException. Is this even possible?

EDIT: Got it. Turns out, as mentioned in the comments, defaults aren't set implicitly. This fixes it:

```
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .append(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy[-MM[-dd]]"))
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 1)
                .toFormatter();
```

Comment: The pattern is invalid, it is not a regular expression and cannot handle missing values like that.

Comment: Then what can handle missing values like that? Is it even possible?

Comment: The error should've given you a hint. A `LocalDate` is comprised of all 3 parts.

Comment: And the output was supposed to consist of all three. 2019-08 should be parsed to 2019-08-01.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45315872/5133585) answer your question?

Comment: In the duplicate, assylias's answer explains why you can't do this (`LocalDate` needs a year, month, and day from the parsed date, which you don't have). Meno's answer shows you how to provide defaults with the `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: probably this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50023654/java-datetimeformatterbuilder-with-optional-pattern-results-in-datetimeparseexce