# String Month-Year to Local Date

Tags: java, date, java-8

I am trying to parse some date-string into a date value, however, using the below code, I am getting an exception:

**My Code**

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                            .parseCaseInsensitive()
                            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM-YYYY"))
                            .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

LocalDate KFilter = LocalDate.parse("August-2021", formatter);
```

**The error log is**

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'August-2021' could not be parsed: 
Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=2021, MonthOfYear=8},
ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

Can you please help me out on the same ?

Comment: Use `y` instead of `Y` and then use `parseDefaulting` for the default value of the day-of-month. There are tens of questions already asked regarding this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between year-of-era and week-based-year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431882/difference-between-year-of-era-and-week-based-year)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM-uuuu"))
            .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

    LocalDate kFilter = YearMonth.parse("August-2021", formatter).atDay(1);

    System.out.println(kFilter);
```

Output:

> 2021-08-01

### What went wrong in your code?

There are two problems with your code:

1. Format pattern strings are case sensitive. Upper case `YYYY` is for week-based year and only useful with a week number. Use either lower case `yyyy` or `uuuu`.
2. Month and year do not define a date, so you cannot readily parse them into a `LocalDate`. I suggest you parse into a `YearMonth` and then convert. In the conversion you need to decise on a day of month. An alternative would be specifying a day of month through `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.parseDefaulting()`.

### Links

Related questions:

- [Difference between year-of-era and week-based-year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431882/difference-between-year-of-era-and-week-based-year)
- [`uuuu` versus `yyyy` in `DateTimeFormatter` formatting pattern codes in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41177442/uuuu-versus-yyyy-in-datetimeformatter-formatting-pattern-codes-in-java)
- [Java DateTimeFormatterBuilder with optional pattern results in DateTimeParseException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50023654/java-datetimeformatterbuilder-with-optional-pattern-results-in-datetimeparseexce)